# VSCode: header file not found even though it is in include path

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include, header-files

For reference I am on an M2 Mac using clang++ to compile code on VSCode. I'm trying to use the Boost Multiprecision c++ library, and I've installed and linked it to VSCode with vcpkg, but the compiler still gives a "file not found" error. Here is my code to test out the boost library:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cpp_int.hpp>

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_int test = 1;
    cout << test << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error that the compiler gives is
`'cpp_int.hpp' file not found`

I've added paths to both `c_cpp_properties.json` and `tasks.json` but the error persists.

##### c_cpp_properties.json

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/arm64-osx/include/**",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/arm64-osx/include/boost/multiprecision/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

##### tasks.json:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-I${vcpkgRoot}/arm64-osx/include/boost/multiprecision/**",
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
}
```

I know that the pathing is correct, because when I type out the #include statement Intellisense is able to autofill `cpp_int.hpp`, so I assume that it's a problem with the compiler and tasks.json rather than c_cpp_properties.json, but I don't what error I've made there. I've tried replacing `${vcpkgRoot}` with the absolute path to no avail, so I don't know why else the compiler is unable to find the header file. For reference, `cpp_int.hpp` is located in `vcpkg > installed > arm64-osx > include > boost > multiprecision`

Comment: Compiler include paths don't use wildcards. You'll also need to just include up to `include` and put `boost/multiprecision` in your `#include`

Comment: @AlanBirtles When I change the includePath in c_cpp_properties.json to `${vscpkgRoot}/arm64-osx/include` and args in tasks.json to `-I${vscpkgRoot}/arm64-osx/include` I get 2 errors on the `#include`: "cannot open source file `boost/multiprecision` and "`boost/multiprecision` file not found"

Comment: Yes, you can't `#include` a directory, you still need to use the file path

Comment: @AlanBirtles `#include<boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>` gives the error: 'boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp' file not found